# Conversion of string to time_t

Tags: visual-c++

Is there a way to convert a string value into time_t format?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's the format of the string?

Comment: what format is your string in? "Vrijdag achttien februari tweeduizend elf"?

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be to parse the string into the various components and use them to fill a tm structure. Once you have the structure filled with data you can use the C function mktime to convert the structure into a time_t type.

There might be more ideal ways to do this in visual C++, but in normal C/C++ this is probably the way i'd do it untill I'd find a better algorithm.